# Comparing Model Item value with bool value

Tags: c#, .net, office365

I am stuck at writing here what if condition is doing means If it finds a property of - `this.ModelItem.Properties["IsGroupCalendar"]` and it is of type `System.Activities.Presentation.Model.ModelPropertyImpl`. This is my code          :

```
public List<FeatureParameter> getOperationParamters(Office365Model activityyModel, string op)
{
    List<FeatureParameter> _listparams = activityyModel.Features.Where(s => s.Name.Equals(op)).FirstOrDefault().Parameters;
    if (this.ModelItem.Properties["IsGroupCalendar"].Value == true)
    {
        List<FeatureParameter> Parametersleft = _listparams;
        int index = Parametersleft.FindIndex(x => x.ParamName.Equals("CalendarId"));
        Parametersleft.RemoveAt(index);
        return Parametersleft;
    }
    return _listparams;
}
```

[image]

I need value to compared with bool value but how can I proceed

Comment: Please don't include tags in the title. That's what tags are for. Also, please format your code. It's basically unreadable otherwise.

Comment: `if (this.ModelItem.Properties["IsGroupCalendar"].Value.GetCurrentValue()) { ... }` ?